# Hover with tooltip.js not working in full calendar version 4.3

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I am trying to implement the mouse hover to show tooltip by following the steps as given in demo example by using tooltip.js and eventRender, it works in the example. But when i try the same in our application, it does not work. 
Note: I am using bootstap 4 in my application.

```
eventRender(info) 
{
    var tooltip = new Tooltip(info.el, {
        title: info.event.extendedProps.description,
        placement: 'top',
        trigger: 'hover',
        container: 'body'
        </div></div>'
    });
}
```

Not working as expected similar to full calendar website

Comment: "does not work" isn't an error message or problem statement. We can't fix "does not work" in code, any more than a mechanic can fix a car that "does not work", without any other information about the problem. How is it not working? What exactly happens when you run the code? Do you get any errors or unexpected behaviour? Also you haven't included enough info about your setup to allow us to understand the issue. You haven't shown what libraries etc you have included, or what CSS you have got. You would need to allow us to compare your version to the fullCalendar demo, in full.

Comment: P.S. If you're using bootstrap you don't need tooltip.js. Use bootstrap's built-in tooltips instead. See https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/tooltips/

Comment: @ADyson IOt does not show up any errors, but it does not show any tooltip on hover

Comment: You probably have some missing or conflicting CSS (especially if bootstrap is also present). As I mentioned above, you haven't given us enough information to know for certain what your issue might be.

Comment: But anyway, like I said, don't waste resources by adding an extra library, use the bootstrap functionality which is already available to you. Bootstrap tooltips and tooltip.js are both based on popper.js (as the documentation notes) so actually the way you set them up is quite similar.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to use bootstrap directly

Comment: did you read the documentation link I gave you above? There are [usage examples](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/tooltips/#usage) provided. Try it. If you get stuck, then update your question. Thanks.